# no suitable method found for getInstance error in java mail api

Tags: java, email, session, jakarta-mail

I am using java mail api to send the mail but stuck with the following error ..

```
no suitable method found for getInstance(java.util,Properties,java.net.Authenticator)
```

And here is my code code snippet in java..

```
 Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password.toCharArray());
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
```

I am getting the mentioned error on following line..

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
```

Please help me .
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You haven't transcribed the error message accurately. Try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've imported `java.net.Authenticator` instead of `javax.mail.Authenticator`. Look at the types specified in the error message, then look at the parameter types in the documentation for `Session.getInstance`.

Comment: Worked but now i am getting eror on this line..public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password.toCharArray());
        }

Comment: @Divyam: Well what did you do to try to understand and fix the error? Did you consult the documentation to check what parameters it accepts, and compare them with the arguments you're trying to pass?

Comment: And as I said in the other post on exactly this same topic, [you don't need to use an Authenticator at all](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).